# Change Position of Post Filterbar via CSS in Wordpress Elementor

Tags: wordpress, post, filter, position, elementor

I have to change things on a wordpress blog, but can't access the php file on server. The Website is built with Wordpress Elementor Pro and I would like to change the position of the blog filter bar to left with custom CSS. Another change I would like to do is to change the order of the categories to the order they have in wordpress editor. Can you help me?

```
I already tried this to change the order, but it didn't work:
li[data-filter="__all"] { order: -20;}
li[data-filter="25"] { order: -10;}
li[data-filter="11"] { order: -9; }
li[data-filter="27"] { order: -8; }
li[data-filter="10"] { order: -7; }
li[data-filter="16"] { order: -6; }
li[data-filter="10"] { order: -5; }
```